# Why is the script not iterating the for loop as expected?

Tags: javascript, html

I want that when the submit button is clicked, the script checks for the input in the bookDirectory object and if it is found, displays its credentials as specified. However, it does not do so and the input bar is simply refreshed. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>This is just a test</title>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>This is going to be the search bar</h1>
  <form>
  <input type="text" id="BookName" name="Book1">
  <input type="submit" id="Searchbtn" onclick="algo()">
</form>
  <script>

  var search = document.getElementById('BookName');

  var bookDirectory = {};
  bookDirectory.book1 = {
    bookName : "book1",
    bookTag1 : "MAIT",
    bookTag2 : "3rd Semester"
  };

  bookDirectory.book2 = {
    bookName : "book2",
    bookTag1 : "NIEC",
    bookTag2 : "1st Semester"
  };

  bookDirectory.book3 = {
    bookName : "book3",
    bookTag1 : "USIT",
    bookTag2 : "5th Semester"
  };

  function algo(search){
      for(var name in bookDirectory){
          if(bookDirectory[name].bookName === search){
              alert(bookDirectory[name].bookTag1);
          }
      }
  };
  </script>
  <h2 id="Book1">This is going to be the book</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The submit button is making a server request and refreshing the page. Try replacing `<input type="submit"` with `<button>`.

Comment: search is the input element, not its value. You need to compare with search.value

Answer (score 0):

You did not pass parameter to the algo function. 
Remove the parameter from the algo function. Change your algo function to

```
function algo(){
      var search = document.getElementById('BookName').value;
      for(var name in bookDirectory){
          if(bookDirectory[name].bookName === search){
              alert(bookDirectory[name].bookTag1);
          }
      }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `type="submit"` to type="button"
   Submit is like making a server request and refreshes the page or use `<button>`

> ```
> <button id="Searchbtn" onclick="algo()"> Test </button>
> ```

2. You are not passing search parameter to the `algo` function

function algo() {

```
    var search = document.getElementById("BookName").value;

    for (var name in bookDirectory) {
        if (bookDirectory[name].bookName === search) {
            alert(bookDirectory[name].bookTag1);
        }
    }
};
```

Get the value from textbox every time the function is called

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
onclick="algo()"
```

to

```
onsubmit="algo()"
```